# Using resource-based authorization on a list in ASP.NET Core/Entity Framework Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, authorization

## Premise

The documented method to apply resource-based authorization in ASP.Net Core is to register an `AuthorizationHandler`, define each `OperationAuthorizationRequirement`, then check access to resources using the `AuthorizeAsync()` method of an injected `IAuthorizationHandler`. [(Reference docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

This is all well and good for checking operations against individual records, but my question is how best to authorize against many resources at once (e.g. checking read permission against a list of records for an index page)?

## Example

Let's say we have a list of orders, and we want to provide users with a list of the ones they have created. To do this with the practice defined by Microsoft's docs, we would first create some static `OperationAuthorizationRequirement` objects:

```cs
public static class CrudOperations
{
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Create =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = nameof(Create) };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Read =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = nameof(Read) };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Update =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = nameof(Update) };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Delete =
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = nameof(Delete) };
}
```

..and then create our AuthorizationHandler:

```cs
public class OrderCreatorAuthorizationHandler :
    AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement, Order>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
        OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement, 
        InspectionManagementUser resource)
    {
        if (context.User == null || resource == null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var currentUserId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        if (resource.CreatedById == currentUserId
            && requirement.Name == CrudOperations.Read.Name) {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This is registered as a service in `Startup.cs`, and is ready to go. In our view logic, we can use our new handler to get a filtered list of orders as such:

```cs
//_context is an injected instance of the application's DatabaseContext
//_authorizationService is an injected instance of IAuthorizationService

var allOrders = await _context.Orders.ToListAsync();

var filteredOrders = allOrders
    .Where(o => _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, o, CrudOperations.Read).Result.Succeeded);
```

This will work just fine, but to me seems extremely computationally expensive as each record is checked separately in memory. This would increase even further as the logic for the authorization handler got more complex (for example, if it involved a database call).

It would presumably be far more efficient to have the database engine filter the list for us as follows:

```cs
var currentUserId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

var filteredOrders = await _context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.CreatedById == currentUserId)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This will execute faster, but we've now bypassed our authorization logic completely. If we later decide to change the restrictions in our `AuthorizationHandler` we must also remember to change it here and anywhere else we use this method. If you ask me that rather seems to defeat the purpose of separating this authorization code out in the first place.

Is there a neat solution to this problem that I'm missing? Any advice or guidance on best practice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I was also looking for some guidance or an example on this, and unfortunately have turned up a few people asking but no answers and also this question.

Answer (score 0):

Resource-based authorization handlers are not designed with your use case in mind. Of course, adding a where clause on the database query is much more efficient, and it also allows to forward paging operations to the database engine as well. If you can handle authorization at the row-level of your database, you shouldn't bother with AuthorizationHandlers.

The feature was designed with an *external* authorization source of truth in mind. This allows to easily implement features such as RBAC with roles membership delegated to a separate subsystem that was not stored within the application RDBMS. Microsoft Identity and Active Directory are obvious examples. Another example is when you're implementing a microservice architecture and your service delegates authorization to a third party.

Regarding implementation, the best approach is to use `IAsyncEnumerables` and `System.Linq.Async`:

```cs
public class OrderController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet("/orders/{manufacturer}")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> ExecuteAsync(
    string manufacturer,
    CancellationToken cancellation)
  {
    var source = database.Orders.AsNoTracking()
      .Where(order => order.Manufacturer == manufacturer)
      .ToAsyncEnumerable();

    var results = await GetAuthorizedOrders(source, cancellation)
      .Skip(10).Take(10).ToArrayAsync(cancellation)
      .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return Ok(results);
  }

  private async IAsyncEnumerable<Order> GetAuthorizedOrders(
    IAsyncEnumerable<Order> source,
    CancellationToken cancellation)
  {
    await foreach (var item in source)
    {
      if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested) { break; }

      var result = await authorizationService
        .AuthorizeAsync(User, item, DelegationRequirement.Default)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

      if (result.Succeeded) { yield return item; }
    }
  }
}
```

```cs
public class DelegationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<DelegationRequirement, Order>
{
  protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
    AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
    DelegationRequirement requirement,
    Order resource)
  {
    // this can do fancy stuff like cache, retry, etc ...
    var delegations = await client.GetDelegationsAsync(
      target: context.User.Identity.Name,
      validity: resource.CreatedOn);

    var has_delegation = delegations
      .Where(deleg => deleg.Source == resource.CreatedBy)
      .Where(deleg => deleg.MaxValue >= resource.Value)
      .Any();

    if (has_delegation) { context.Succeed(requirement); }
  }
}
```

When using this approach with two separate infrastructure for business data and authorization, the benefit is that you have separate code to access each infrastructure. So if any need to evolve due to new constraints, you can change the code with limited worries on breaking the other part.